# Randomising a Sequence

Tags: probability

Let $a[1], a[2], \ldots a[n]$ be a sequence of $n$ numbers. At each stage an integer $i$ is uniformly and randomly chosen between $1$ and $n$ and then the index of $a[i]$ is changed to $1$ while the indices of all terms from $1$ to $i-1$  are incremented by $1$. If this process is repeated m times what is the probability that the the term with the index $j$ represents the $k^\text{th}$ term in the original sequence? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the numbers present initially in the array? 1,2,3...n ?